# Getting first 20 words without excerpt

Tags: excerpt, the-content

I'm working on my own custom theme (first custom WP work so I'm a real beginner) and need help in listing the first 20 words of a list of recent posts.

I managed to solve this with manual? excerpt but I would like to just get the first 20 words of the content, but not sure how to best do that. The application is in a list on my start page.

My current code looks like this

```
    <?php
    $cdRP = get_theme_mod('cd_recent_posts', '3');
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => $cdRP );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<div class="grid-cell"><a class="fpItems" href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"]) ) {
            echo  '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"],'thumbnail') . '</div>';
        }
        echo '<div>'
        . '<h3>' . $recent["post_title"] . '</h3>'

        . '</div></a></div>';
    }
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

All of this happens outside the loop. I tried to find the answer in the forums, but failed, so sorry if this has been asked and answered before. Trying my best to learn to code this wonderful tool my self :)

Comment: It is part of the process to select an answer as solution by giving it the green check mark. Feel free to chose your own.

Comment: oh, missed that. Thank you so much for pointing it out (blush)

Comment: No worries, it is a common effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`wp_trim_words()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/)

```
wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 20 )
```

As you're outside the main loop

```
wp_trim_words( $recent[ 'post_content' ], 20 )
```

If you want to apply the same filters as to `the_content()` in the main loop

```
wp_trim_words( apply_filters( 'the_content', $recent[ 'post_content' ] ), 20 )
```

Comment: Since you're outside The Loop, you might need to use `wp_trim_words( get_the_content( $recent["ID"] ), 20 );`.

Comment: @PatJ `get_the_content` doesn't take the `ID`, but he has the `post_content` already available

Comment: Life savers. Thank you guys :)

I managed to guess by just typing logical stuff that $recent["post_content"] got the content, but didn't manage to trim it. Hoped that $recent[post_excerpt"] worked, but no such luck ;)

Thank your your help. both of you @PatJ and Nicolai

Comment: @Per My pleasure and anytime.

Comment: @Nicolai Whoops, good catch.

Comment: @PatJ I already had written your exact suggestion, before I remembered the restriction.

Answer (score 2):

Working Solution turned out to be simple :)

```
    <?php
    $cdRP = get_theme_mod('cd_recent_posts', '3');
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => $cdRP );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<div class="grid-cell"><a class="fpItems" href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"]) ) {
            echo  '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"],'thumbnail') . '</div>';
        }
        echo '<div>'
        . '<h3>' . $recent["post_title"] . '</h3>'

        . wp_trim_words( $recent["post_content"], 20 )

        . '</div></a></div>';
    }
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the following;

```
$content = get_the_content();
echo substr($content, 0, 20);
```

or

```
$content = get_the_excerpt();
echo substr($content, 0, 20);
```

This will limit the character count to 20.

Comment: That'll trim to 20 *characters*, not *words*, though.